# Identity Server login asks for code challenge

Tags: identityserver4

I have 3 projects

- IdentityServer
- MVC App
- Web Api

That is works fine

MVC App: ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", opt =>
{
    opt.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    opt.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
    opt.ClientId = "mvc";
    opt.ResponseType = "code id_token";
    opt.Scope.Add("openid");
    opt.Scope.Add("email");
    opt.Scope.Add("office");
    opt.ClientSecret = "secret";
    opt.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    opt.SaveTokens = false;
});
```

And the client

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName= "MVC Demo",
    Description = "MVC Demo",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44344/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44344/signout-callback-oidc" },
    BackChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44344/signout-oidc",
    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:44344/signout-oidc",
    AllowedScopes = { "openid", "email", "office", "profile" },
}
```

Logging into to the client works absolutely fine, but the issue arises when I want to add a hybrid flow (following the Microsoft academy video from 2019 on it) and it simply isn't working. It's giving me the error `code challenge required` when logging in - I'm trying to update it so that it can call the API from the MVC app

This is what I update:

I add the scope to the "oidc" scheme, and set the client secret

```
opt.Scope.Add("api1");
opt.ClientSecret = "secret";
```

And against the client I add the client secret, add `api1` to the allowed scopes, and update the flow to `hybrid`

```
ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
AllowedScopes = { "openid", "email", "office", "profile", "api1" },
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
```

From then, when I click login I get this
[image]

I've spent the last 2 days trying to figure out what I'm missing from this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IdentityServer expects that you use the PKCE extension and to disable it you can set the RequirePkce parameter to false. However, for security reasons you should try to use this feature.

It says [here](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/reference/models/client/):

*RequirePkce
Specifies whether clients using an authorization code based grant type must send a proof key (defaults to true).*

Also, it's recommended not to use the Hybrid flow. Do read [this article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/ASPNET-Core-using-Proof-Key-for-Code-Exchange-PKCE) for more details.

In the source code [here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs,5cc7fe6410c2ed93), it says:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enables or disables the use of the Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) standard.
    /// This only applies when the <see cref="ResponseType"/> is set to <see cref="OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code"/>.
    /// See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7636.
    /// The default value is `true`.
    /// </summary>
    public bool UsePkce { get; set; } = true;
```

So, its disabled for hybrid flow?

Comment: Okay that makes sense. What would I need to update to use PKCE? I’m completely new to this. The goal I’m looking for is the MVC app to set an access token against the API app

Comment: i would aim to use the auth code flow instead of the hybrid flow.

Comment: updated my answer. so I would disable it in the server